# How to create a file manager for registered users using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm working on a fairly ambitious project for me. There is a complete tutorial that describes how to create an environment on the web site (a kind of user panel) where registered users can upload files, audio, video etc .. edit the name, create folders, and share it with other users. Manage their information, update or modify them. Create folders with random names when loading files on the server. The graphics look I can create, but interaction with the database to retrieve the information of each user and show them in the panel I can not do it without having the necessary knowledge. Every advice, guide and tutorials is well accepted. (Forgive my dingy English)

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is server-side. You need to work with modules for what you want to do. For example: `express` to easily work with GET, POST data; and other modules you can find on NPM.